# Does water-based paint expire?

Tags: paint

I have almost a whole gallon of Behr white semi-gloss that is 6 years old.  When I opened it, it looked good.  But is it expired?

Comment: How was the paint stored through the 6 years?  Did it experience high heat or freezing temperatures?  What are you planning to use it for?

Comment: it was in a shed so yes, high heat and low temps. painting some plywood shelves and possibly tin ceiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a specific answer for you but all of the data sheets from Behr I've come across seem to suggest that they have a shelf life of two years (IF unopened).  For example: http://www.behrpro.com/cma/BehrPro/Marketing/Products/TDS/7050_27050.pdf

I'd say 6 years is pushing your luck and I wouldn't recommend using it for highly visible or large projects... or project where you need to blend the color with something else.  Maybe you can use it for some minor trivial touch-up projects?